# Problems With Dynamic Form Using JavaScript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, error-handling

I'm having trouble with these files, see if you guys can help me out :)
I get an object required error..

**index.php**

```
<?php 
  //Start session
  session_start(); 
  //Require functions.php
  require("functions.php");
  //Require posts.php
  require("posts.php");
?>
<html>
<body>
<title>Log Into Booking System</title>
  <?php 
    //Call function to display login
    displayLogin();
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**posts.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sublogin']))
{
    //Check that all fields were typed in and are not null
    if(!$_POST['user'] || !$_POST['pass'])
    {
        //Call function to display error
        printText("Please make sure all required fields are filled in.");
    }
    else
    {
        //Here is some database checking
    }
}
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php   
function displayLogin()
{
    //Break php, then return to PHP
    ?> 
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="user" maxlength="30"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="30"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div id='error'></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="sublogin" value="Login"></td></tr> 
    </table>    
    </form>
    <?
}

function printText($txtmsg)
{
    ?>      
    <!-- Set up the displayError javascript function -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function displayError()
        {                   
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = <?echo $txtmsg;?>;
        }
    </script>
    <!-- Call function to Display the error -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        displayError();
    </script>
    <?
}
?>
```

I'm pretty sure

```
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML
```

Is causing me problems, i think it might have to do with how im calling it, like it dosent know what its looking for..

Thanks guys much appreciated,

Jenny

EDIT: Here is the paste of what jQuerybeast tried to do, http://pastebin.com/jj0RVMAd

**SOLUTION: Who knew it was this easy? You MUST change the order of where posts.php is required as well as make sure you don't call a javascript function within functions.php because that will execute the javascript above the form and therefore giving a null object error.**

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Log Into Booking System</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

<?php 
//Start session
session_start(); 
//Require functions.php
require("functions.php");
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
//Call function to display login
displayLogin(); 
//Require posts.php
require("posts.php");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**posts.php**

```
<?php
//POST: Main login page
if (isset($_POST['sublogin']))
{
    //Display error if feilds are not filled in
    if(!$_POST['user'] || !$_POST['pass'])
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Please make sure all required fields are filled in.";</script>';
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Some database minipulation here....
        //...
        if ($_POST['user'] != $databaseUsername)
        {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Please make sure your username is correct.";</script>';
        return false;
        }
        elseif($_POST['pass'] != $databasePassword)
        {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Please make sure your password is correct.";</script>';
        return false;           
        }
    }
    return true;
}

?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php


//Function: Display main.php login
function displayLogin()
{

    //Break php, then return to PHP
    ?> 
    <div style="float: left; padding: 10px; width:20%;">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    </legend>
    <form name = "mainlogin" action="" method="post">
    <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="user" maxlength="30"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="30"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="remember">
    <font size="2">Remember username and password</td></tr> 
    <tr><td><div id="error"></div></tr><td>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="sublogin" value="Login"></td></tr> 
    </table>    
    </form>
    </fieldset>
    </div>

    <?php

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is that the PHP-echoed string inside the Javascript function doesn't have quotation marks around it.

Change:

```
    function displayError()
    {                   
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = <?echo $txtmsg;?>;
    }
```

To:

```
    function displayError()
    {                   
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "<?echo $txtmsg;?>";
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Comment: This can happen if the `<div>` element with id "error" isn't present on the page at the time the javascript is ran. Another potential issue is that `require("posts.php");` is executed before the `<head>` of the HTML document, and it effectively outputs a `<script>` section (when some POST values aren't present). This might have some unintended consequences.

Comment: I think if you follow my code you will see that <div> is present when the code is ran because i only get an error after hitting submit(thats when i call the javascript function).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is caused from functions.php is because you open and close PHP the opposite way.

```
Instead of ?>  <?
Try: <?    ?>
```

Which is this:

```
function displayLogin()
{
    //Break php, then return to PHP
    <?
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="user" maxlength="30"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="30"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div id='error'></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="sublogin" value="Login"></td></tr> 
    </table>    
    </form>
    ?>
}


function printText($txtmsg)
{
    <?      
    <!-- Set up the displayError javascript function -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function displayError()
        {                   
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = <?echo $txtmsg;?>;
        }
    </script>
    <!-- Call function to Display the error -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        displayError();
    </script>
    ?>
}
```

Comment: his comment `//Break php, then return to PHP` would indicate that was intentional. He's leaving PHP, then reentering.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add the php tags to this post(silly me). Maybe you can find another problem?

Comment: @vascowhite ahh see what you mean. Sorry, the code wasn't clear posted.

Comment: @xoxo-jenny-shu-oxox Try <php ?> instead of <?. Some servers don't have short-tags enabled.

Comment: @jQuerybeast  Short tags work on my server, i have used them before

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = <?echo $txtmsg;?>;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = '<?= $txtmsg; ?>';
```

or

```
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = '<?php echo $txtmsg; ?>';
```

Comment: The new error i am getting is 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Comment: I think you need to stop the form submitting for your JS to work. Add `onSubmit="return"` to your submit button and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = '<?php echo $txtmsg; ?>';
```

and

It seems short tag is not enabled on your server. Please make sure.
Or always use `<?php ?>` instead of `<? ?>`

Comment: Short tags to work, i have used them else where just fine. I am getting a 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object  error now.

Comment: If you are getting a null is because the document past the script yet. Try to put all the JS in function docloaded() { and change the <body> to <body onload="docloaded();">

Comment: @jQuerybeast Now im getting two errors that are Object expected as soon as the page finish loading. A null one when i click the button(same error i guess?)

Comment: Can you update your question or make a fiddle of what you currently have?

Comment: @jQuerybeast  All i did on index.php was replace <body> with <body onload="docloaded();"> . In functions.php i made a javascript section docloaded() that had the javascript function displayError(){document.getelement....} in it. The call for  displayError() was still in printText()

Comment: try <body onload="displayError();">

Comment: Oh and also instead of having it display my message, i just wanted it to print the word 'lol' in the form

Comment: hot dang it displayed lol when i called displayError() using <body onload="displayError();">; ! But when i call the function from inside printText it will give me the null or not object error as usual:(

Comment: It seems that it will not run displayError(); correctly unless using <body onload="docloaded();"> . Do you know why?

Comment: @jQuerybeast This is very odd. Is there somewhere i can post the code for each file? Maybe paste bin?

Comment: @jQuerybeast http://pastebin.com/jj0RVMAd   Here is the paste. I'm starting to get a head ache, i should have this code working in no time.